# how does github mark the status color of your branch

Tags: git, github, git-shell

in git shell I regularly see sthis

```
myProject $ [branch1]
```

where 'branch1' is blue whenever in sync, or green if its not.
but what does this color indicator mean, what does this compare to? and how to change this to a different fork if its comparing to the wrong one.
e.g.

```
myProject $ [branch1] git remote -v
```

lists 5 forks with their own branches, how can I can set the color indicator to compare to say myFork or otherPeople's fork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git uses the git configuration file to set the colors. Typlically your global .gitconfig file is located in your home directory.

[Here is an example of my .gitconfig file](https://github.com/AJ-Acevedo/dotfiles/blob/master/gitconfig.erb#L41) and how I set the git color status.

Git allows you to set the color for:
color.branch
color.diff
color.interactive
color.status

Here are some further details on git colors:
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Colors-in-Git